# How copy the data from one column to another column in the same table with different data type in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to copy data from  `VISITSAUTHORIZED  VARCHAR2(11)` column to  `VISITORS  NUMBER(5)` column. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What's stopping you? Are there specific problems you are facing?

Comment: yes actually i need to change a datatype of VISITSAUTHORIZED varchar to number without deleting the data .

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table <table> add visitors number(5);

update <table> set visitors = visitsauthorized;

alter table <table> drop column visitsauthorized;
```

Of course, this approach will fail if visitsauthorized contains non-numeric values.

Alternativaly, you might want to use [dbms_redefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11668), but frankly, my experiences with it were not very positive, at least on 11i (see for example [this dba.exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55081/why-is-sqlplus-desc-table-not-showing-not-null-constraints-after-using-dbms-re))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna change structure of your table mean,

Use the following query if your `VISITSAUTHORIZED` length is 5 or less

```
UPDATE table_name SET VISITORS=to_number(VISITSAUTHORIZED)
```

if `VISITSAUTHORIZED` length is more than 5 mean  trim your `VISITSAUTHORIZED` column then update it like,

```
UPDATE table_name SET VISITORS=to_number(SUBSTR(VISITSAUTHORIZED,1,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

While coping use the `cast()` function.[For reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm)